# Windows Server 2008 R2/IIS 7 refuses all outside tcp connections

Tags: tcp, connection, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-x64

I am unable to connect, for example, via http to a brand new installation of 64-bit Windows Server 2008. The server is on a domain, but is not DC (that's another problem altogether).

The IIS7 is running on the server and the website is accessible locally via http://localhost, but when I try to connect from another machine on the same network, the connections is refused, even though Windows Firewall is disabled.

I am able to connect to and browse the shared folders on the server using Windows Explorer, so it is not a physical connection issue. I can ping other machines on the network from the server, but trying to ping the server from another machine results in "Destination host unreachable".

As far as I can tell, the server refuses any TCP connections from any machine. I am thinking, there must be some other configuration setting that I am missing... Please, help.

NS

Comment: clearly belongs on serverfault.com

Comment: Uh, I didn't even know such existed... [blush] I'll try to repost there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is embarrassignly simple, and the credit goes to Ashley Steel, on ServerFault.com for asking just the right questions. It turns out that the DNS was resolving the name of the server incorrectly, because the machine was named the same as an old, since decommissioned workstation that used to live on the same subnet.

The solution: rename the server.

NS[Now hiding under a rock]

Answer (score 0):

Like in Windows 7 the behaviour is determined by the network type (home, work, internet) the OS thinks it is connected to... even with a disabled firewall it respects these settings and accordingly refuses/allows connections...

Comment: How do I find out what it thinks? All the other machines (even Win7) have no problem communicating over the same network. Also, I just tried, and the connection works fine in the other direction, i.e. I can connect from the server to, say, a Win7 machine via TCP/IP.

Comment: you look into network center (sorry I only have a german OS at hand) and see what network/access type is displayed (home/private - work/office - internet)...

Comment: "Network and Sharing Center", it says "Access type: Internet".

Comment: If you change that to private/home then the connection should be possible

Comment: There is, but it ony gives me the options to: 1) connect to the Internet, 2) connect to a workplace (i.e. VPN), and 3) setup a dialup connection, none of which are good. Furthermore, the current network connection type is not clickable and says: Domain network. It's as if it could not be re-configured.